# get cell number within a distance of one point (raster)

Tags: r, cell, distance, spatial, raster

I need to get the cell numbers within a distance (e.g., 10 km) of one point using R, but I didn't figure out how to handle it for the raster data.

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncols=10, nrows=10)
cellFromXY(r, c(2,2)) # get the cell number of one point
```

How to get the cell numbers within a distance of one point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use extract with the buffer option and cellnumbers=TRUE

```
r <- raster(ncols=100, nrows=100)
  r[]<-runif(ncell(r))

xy <- cbind(-50, seq(-80, 80, by=20))
extract(r, xy[1:3,], buffer=1000000,cellnumbers=TRUE)
```