# Minimum elevation within km

Tags: r, spatial, raster

Trying to find the minimum elevation within 10km of a certain latitude and longitude using R.

So far I have

```
dem <- getData("SRTM", lat=42.90, lon=-78.85, path = datadir)
plot(dem)
```

I know I need to create spatial points and eventually buffer/extract the information.

When I try:

```
buffdem <- buffer(dem, width=10000)
```

It does not work because I don't have any points.

I tried

```
dem <- getData("SRTM", lat=42.90, lon=-78.85, path = datadir)
coords <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(100),
  y = rnorm(100)
)
coordinates(dem)

spdf = SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords, dem)
```

I get the following error:

> Error in validObject(.Object) :    invalid class
>   “SpatialPointsDataFrame” object: invalid object for slot "data" in
>   class "SpatialPointsDataFrame": got class "RasterLayer", should be or
>   extend class "data.frame"

Comment: A reproducible example, please.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to buffer the points. Do a focal `min` of the raster and then use `extract` - see `?focal`

Comment: "reproducible" means you provide us with a sample data set we can use to demonstrate/test solutions: http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000

Comment: I see, I will try to the focal min. Thanks!

Comment: I would post an example but that ftp is painfully slow for me. I'll see if I can find a smaller tile.

Comment: In retrospect I think that buffering points is probably wise. Seeing as you're working with ~90 m data, I'm guessing a 10000 m (about a 111 x 111 window cell) focal minimum will take a while to calculate. In this case, you should be able to just do `buffer(dem, coords, width=10000, fun=min)`.

Comment: worked, all set, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think this accomplishes what you need:

```
library(raster)
#elevation <- getData("SRTM", lat=42.90, lon=-78.85)
#poi <- cbind(lon=-78.85, lat=42.90)
```

using a smaller example data set for quicker download:

```
elevation <- getData('alt', country='CHE')
poi <- cbind(8.13, 46.47)

e <- extract(elevation, poi, buffer=10000)

sapply(e, min, na.rm=TRUE)
```

By the way, this is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996256/get-cell-number-within-a-distance-of-one-point-raster?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32830821/aggregate-the-values-in-a-raster-that-lie-within-a-given-distance-from-a-given-p?rq=1) question.